# Rijndael Padding in Python

Tags: python, encryption, aes, padding, rijndael

I know where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it. The problem is with the padding. I have absolutely no idea about it and how it works. I tried searching online but nothing seemed to help. I am trying to implement this function to work with my [website](https://hackhex.com/). The python encrypts and sends the data and PHP decrypts it.

Here's the actual code of my python:

```
from rijndael.cipher.crypt import new
from rijndael.cipher.blockcipher import MODE_CBC
import base64

PADDING = b'.'

def r_pad(payload, block_size=32):
    return payload + (block_size - len(payload) % block_size) * PADDING

KEY = 'lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5'
IV = '741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y'
plain_text = "A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length."

rjn = new(KEY, MODE_CBC, IV, blocksize=32)
encd = rjn.encrypt(r_pad(plain_text))
data = base64.b64encode(encd)
print(data)

rjn = new(KEY, MODE_CBC, IV, blocksize=32)
data = base64.b64decode(data)
decd = rjn.decrypt(r_pad(data))
print (decd)
```

This is the output:

> Dv0Y/AFXdFMlDrcldFCu8v5o9zAlLNgyM+vO+PFeSrqWdzP1S1cumviFiEjNAjz5njnMMC9lfxsBl71x5y+xCw==
>
> A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length.............................Å¿:è°⌐┘n┤«╞Px╜:æC┬♣╬Q┤▼«U_♦â☻ìr

I need the output of the encrypted string to be something like this:

> Dv0Y/AFXdFMlDrcldFCu8v5o9zAlLNgyM+vO+PFeSrpO8Ve82mdUcc4rkzp9afDYc75NmkSd4mdflt38kceOdA==
>
> A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length

I tried to make RIJNDAEL256 function out of this code:

```
EncryptRJ256("lkirwf897+22#bbtrm8814z5qq=498j5", "741952hheeyy66#cs!9hjv887mxx7@8y", "A padded string to BLOCKSIZE length.")

Public Function EncryptRJ256(ByVal prm_key As String, ByVal prm_iv As String, ByVal prm_text_to_encrypt As String) As String
    Dim s As String = prm_text_to_encrypt
    Dim managed2 As New RijndaelManaged With {
    .Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
    .Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
    .BlockSize = 256
}
    Dim stream As New MemoryStream
    Dim stream2 As New CryptoStream(stream, managed2.CreateEncryptor(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(prm_iv)), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
    Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s)
    stream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
    stream2.FlushFinalBlock()
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray)
End Function
```

Can anyone please help? I am lost at this point. :/

Comment: One big mistake you're making is working with strings. Encryption doesn't operate on text; it operates on *bytes*. Under the hood, it's encoding all your strings to bytes so it can work with them. The problem with that is that some characters take more than 1 byte to represent. So even if you have a nicely padded string, there's no guarantee that it'll still have the same length after it's converted to bytes. Encode first, pad later. *Always* work with bytes when encrypting or compressing data.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost too. Why do you have both python and visual basic code? What is your actual problem?

Comment: The .net code was for reference. I was trying to make the same function in python.